# Cannot do "split" in chrome's console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to get links from one page. Here's a simple code to get all links from certain dom element.

```
var $ = jQuery;
var page = $("#main .entry p");
var rez = [];

for(var i=0; i<page.length;i++) {
    var title = $(page[i]).find("a").text();
    var info = $(page[i]).text();
    var page_url = $(page[i]).find("a").attr("href");
    rez.push({
        title: title,
        page_url: page_url,
        info: info
    });
}
```

I am using this code in Chrome browser's console.

Everything works ok. `rez` array is populated, and I can veryfy it by something like `console.table(rez)`.

Now I am trying to strip certain part from urls collected in previous step by using `split`

```
for(var i=0; i<rez.length;i++) {
    console.log(rez[i].page_url); // <- this works
    console.log(rez[i].page_url.split("http://something...")[1] ); // <- this fails
}
```

**Important note!** I am doing it all in one step by copying entire code (rez populating code and rez iterating in order to make split).
And I am getting this error in console:

```
VM7064:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:18:29
```

Why??

Comment: Can you add the log of the `console.log(rez[i].page_url); // <- this works` ?

Comment: I will change it a bit so not to reveal true url, but it will be something like `http://something...like-this.com/blablabla`

Comment: Are you sure EVERY item in the array has a `page_url` property? If one of them doesn't, when trying to access `res[i].page_url` it would be `undefined`, which would explain the error message that you are trying to call `split` on `undefined`. You might have to test for `page_url` before `if (res[i].page_url !== undefined) { /* do split */}`.

Answer (score 1):

The split() function is used to split a string into an array of substrings. In split function as parameter you have to put a separator for example:

`"http://something...like-this.com/blablabla".split("/");`

This will return you an array `["http:", "", "something...like-this.com", "blablabla"]`

In your case you try to split by some text **"http://something..."** and to get the second element of the array **[1]**. This will return you undefined in all your cases.

Comment: I will get the same error if I will try to do something like `rez[i].page_url.split("t")` which should definitely return some array, but I am getting the same error

Comment: Can you try this and add the result from the log:

var p_link = rez[i].page_url;
console.log(p_link);
console.log(p_link.split("t"));